# makefile file format not recognized

Tags: c, makefile

what i'm doing wrong?
And can you send some helpful links to make my work with makefiles easier and better?

```
get_next_line.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:27: recipe for target 'gnl' failed
make: *** [gnl] Error 1
```

+++

```
SRC = gnl.c
OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)
INCLUDES = gnl.h
NAME = gnl
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -Wextra
CC = gcc
DIR = LIBFT

%.o: %.c $(SRC) $(INCLUDES)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJ)
        make -C $(DIR)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(NAME) $(OBJ) -L. $(DIR)/libft.a
clean:
        make clean -C $(DIR)
        rm -f $(OBJ)

fclean:
        make fclean -C $(DIR)
        rm -f $(NAME)

re: fclean all
```

Comment: Does the makefile contain line numbers?

Comment: nope,sry, it's copied from Vim

Comment: Looks like a rotten object file. Do a `make clean` and try again.

Comment: I don't see any reference to `get_next_line.c` - Is this your real Makefile? If yes, then the problem might be in the `LIBFT` Makefile. Write a hello world in test.c+test.h and comment the `make -C $(DIR)` to check it.

Comment: Give that the error is reported from line 27 of the makefile, and refers to an object file that is not a target in the *25 line* makefile posted, this is clearly not the makefile that generated the error shown!  You are not helping yourself by posting misleading information - answers will be a guess at best.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a `make` error by itself. It says

```
get_next_line.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
```

so *that* is your problem. Somehow you managed to have a `.o` file in your directory that is corrupted. Remove it and things will go better.

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood the error message.  The error message is referring to the file *`get_next_line.o`*, not the makefile.

It is the linker (*ld*) that is reporting the error not *make*.  The  command that has failed is that for the target `gnl`.

Answer (score 1):

It can even be simpler...
It just happened to me with a Makefile. 
In the line (in the Makefile) that creates the executable, where there are different names of objects .o, there was a typo. I left the name of the file .cu (CUDA format) instead of .o.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error recently, and I have a couple of suggestions that might help. My problem was not a bad .o file, but rather a 32-bit installation rather than a 64-bit installation. If this is the case for you, too, you might get more complete functionality by trying this solution.

In my case, the `makefile`(s) in question needed different `CFLAGS` depending on whether the installation was 64-bit or 32-bit. Here are some lines from the [`README`](https://github.com/chinshr/sctk/blob/master/README) of the project I was trying to `make`.

> `By default, the C/C++ software are compiled in 32 bits with the options (-Os) but can be compiled in 64 bits, -m64 is added to the CFLAGS variable in <certain makefiles in the project are listed>`

My suggestion is to first try adding `-m64` to your `CFLAGS`. If that doesn't work, delete the `-m64` and replace it with `-Os`.

That is, first try having the following line:

```
CFLAGS = -g3 -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -DREPLICATION_ENABLED -DJOURNALING_ENABLED -m64
```

Then, from the command line, run

```
make clean
```

Followed by whatever `make` commands you use for your install.

If that doesn't work, change the line in question to

```
CFLAGS = -g3 -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -DREPLICATION_ENABLED -DJOURNALING_ENABLED -Os
```

Then `make clean` and the other `make` stuff.

If some of the C objects are 64-bit and some are 32-bit (I don't know if such a situation actually exists), you might have to do something different.

This worked in my case, details of which you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50278663/6505499).

Please comment to let me know if it works for you.